# Without the use of canonical forms, why does $\ker (A - cI) = \ker (A - cI)^{2}$ imply that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a complex matrix such that $\ker (A - cI) = \ker (A - cI)^{2}$ for all $c \in \mathbb{C}$. Without using canonical forms, why must $A$ be diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

Because, in this case,

$$
\ker (A - cI) = \ker (A - cI)^n \ ,
$$

for all $n$.

Particularly,

$$
\mathrm{dim}\ker (A - cI)
$$

will always agree with the *algebraic multiplicity* of the eigenvalue $c$. And then, because of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), $A$ will be diagonalizable.

EDIT. Using walcher's idea: if $\ker(A-cI) = \ker(A-cI)^2$, then, for every $n$, if $u\in \ker(A-cI)^n$, then $0 = (A-cI)^2(A-cI)^{n-2}u$. So, $(A-cI)^{n-2}u\in \ker(A-cI)^2 = \ker(A-cI)$. Hence, $(A-cI)^{n-1}u =(A-cI)(A-cI)^{n-2}u =  0$. So, in fact $u \in \ker (A-cI)^{n-1}$. By induction, you get $u \in \ker(A-cI)$.

Comment: Let $m$ be the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $c$, I'm a bit confused as to why the first centered equation implies that $\dim\ker(A - cI) = m$?

Comment: Because, in general, for every eigenvalue, geometric multiplicity (aka $\mathrm{dim}\ker(A-cI)$) is less or equal than the algebraic one. So you have a chain of *strict* inclusions $\ker (A-cI) \subset \ker (A-cI)^2 \subset \dots \subset \ker (A-cI)^n \subset \dots$ till we reach the algebraic multiplicity. If at one point of this chain, we have $\ker (A-cI)^m = \ker (A-cI)^{m+1}$, then the chain stabilizes. So, in your case, $\ker (A-cI) = \ker (A-cI)^2 =\ker (A-cI)^n $, where $n$ is the algebraic multiplicty. If this is true for all eigenvalues $c$, $A$ diagonalizes.

Answer (score 0):

Because every complex matrix has a basis of generalised eigenvectors (over $\Bbb C$ the characteristic polynomial splits into a product of distinct linear factors).
Fix such a basis and suppose some vector $v$ belonging to the eigenvalue $c$ is not an eigenvector, i.e. $(A-cI)v\neq 0$. Let $n$ be the smallest natural number such that $(A-cI)^nv=0$ (recall $v$ is a generalised eigenvector), then $n\ge 2$ and $w=(A-cI)^{n-2}v\in\text{ker}(A-cI)^2$, but $w\notin\text{ker}(A-cI)$, contradiction.